# Uncommon IP notations

Tags: ip, ipv6, ipv4, notation

I know that it is possible to write IPs in IPv4 as an integer e.g. `2130706433` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

What is the reason for this possibility?

Is there a similar notation for IPv6?

I tried `ping -6 1` as a try to ping `::1`, but that don't work (the host would not exists).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPv4 addresses can be represented in multiple ways. For example the default loopback IP can be one of:

- 127.0.0.1
- 0177.0.0.1
- 0x7f.0.0.1
- 127.0.1
- 127.1
- 2130706433
- 017700000001
- 0x7f000001

The first notation (full 8-bit decimal dotted) is in wide usage, the remaining ones are seldom used but allowed by the [inet_addr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/inet_addr.html) POSIX standard function. Only the first familiar notation has been retained in the newer [inet_ntop/inet_pton](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/inet_ntop.html) POSIX standard functions which process both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

With IPv6, 16-bit hexadecimal dotted notation with an optional decimal dotted trailer (for embedded IPv4) and also an optional zero compression is what the standard defines.

eg:

- 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:9370:7334
- 2001:0db8:85a3::8a2e:9370:7334

There are then still multiple representations of a single address. To avoid the resulting confusion [RFC 5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952) recommends a canonical form that allows a unique notation.

Answer (score 2):

An IPv4 address is just a 32bit number. You could represent it in any way you can represent such a number (decimal, hex, octal). The dotted notation `a.b.c.d` is just much more practical.

You can do the same thing with IPv6 addresses, except that those are 128bit numbers - even harder to grok in decimal form.

The usual tools will only deal with usual notations. Decimal isn't one of those.