# How is it possible for a domain name to exist without a TLD?

Tags: dns

For instance, I found this website while going through my Spam folder:

http://0x505d5a7a/index.php

... how? I mean shouldn't this URL not even work?

EDIT: The decimal and octal representations do not (or cannot) work:

http://1348295290/index.php

http://12027255172/index.php

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

But the dotted hex does:

http://0x50.0x5d.0x5a.0x7a/index.php

And so does the dotted octal:

http://0120.0135.0132.0172/index.php

Comment: I missed your update, but that is strange since I am able to ping 1348295290 (which results again to the right IP).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncommon IP notations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9340298/995926).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hexadecimal noted IP address so this is a valid url.

My browser directly shows me the IP 80.93.90.122

Comment: Wow! I never knew IPs could be encoded in hexadecimal. That's pretty cool.

Comment: An IPv4 address is just a 32-bit integer (and an IPv6 address is a 128-bit integer). That it's nearly always written out as four 8-bit integers with dots between them is only convention.

Comment: I knew that much. What I meant was that I didn't know browsers would accept any other notations.